# Simple query to exclude rows from joined table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following simple query (sorry about generic syntax)

```
  select distinct tbl_310.id
        from schema_1.tbl_310 tbl_310
        left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_310_field_71 field_58 on field_58.tbl_310_id=tbl_310.id
        WHERE field_58.tbl_342_id != 13
```

in the join table (schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_310_field_71), there are 2 rows where tbl_342_id=13

```
id  tbl_342_id
14  13
17  13
```

My intent/goal is to retrieve all the record from tbl_310 which have NOT been associated with tbl_342_id=13. So, exclude items (14 and 17). When I run the query above. I get the following.
Notice that item 14 shows up, because it's associated with different tbl_342_id's other than 13.

```
tbl_310_id
11
8
10
7
13
5
15
16
14
12
```

Is there an efficient way to return records which have NOT been linked to the id specified (13) without doing a subquery?

The following query works, but I'm wondering if it's the most efficient way to solve this.

```
 select distinct tbl_310.id
        from schema_1.tbl_310 tbl_310
       join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_310_field_71 field_58 on field_58.tbl_310_id=tbl_310.id
        where tbl_310.id not in (
        SELECT
            tbl_310_id
        FROM
           schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_310_field_71 field_58
        WHERE
            field_58.tbl_342_id = 13)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't work...14 is still returned.

Comment: If you're going to use a subquery then you don't need the join. If you look at the query plan you'll see that the subquery is slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl_310
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            tbl1_342
        WHERE
            tbl_310.tbl_342_id = tbl1_342.id
    );
```

if you want to do it with the join also its possible but not optimal:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tbl_310.id
FROM
    schema_1.tbl_310                               tbl_310
    LEFT JOIN schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_310_field_71 field_58
        ON field_58.tbl_310_id = tbl_310.id
        AND field_58.tbl_342_id = 13
WHERE
    field_58.id IS NULL
```

Comment: thx, I can do it with subquery...but I was hoping there was a way without using a subquery.

Comment: this is the most efficient way  in this case to  get that result

Comment: if you want the join i also added it

Comment: looking at the NOT Exists query you put, I'm not what you meant with tbl1_342 ?  I tried the following, but it returns o rows.  select distinct tbl_310.id
        from schema_1.tbl_310 tbl_310
       join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_310_field_71 field_58 on field_58.tbl_310_id=tbl_310.id
  where NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT
            1
        FROM
            schema_1.tbl_342
        WHERE
            tbl_342_id = tbl_342.id)

Comment: I updated my question with a version that works, but curious if this is the most efficient. I would prefer to keep the logic in the WHERE clause, as these queries are built dynamically and it's easier to maintain in the WHERE clause.

Comment: sorry whatever your second table name was, and yes not exists version is the most

Answer (score -1):

```
select tbl_310.id
from schema_1.tbl_310 tbl_310
    left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_310_field_71 field_58
        on field_58.tbl_310_id = tbl_310.id
group by tbl_310.id
having count(case when field_58.tbl_342_id = 13 then 1 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.